# Reshape image data

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to reshape data from a given file using a function in R. However, when I run the code, I get the error: Incorrect number of subscripts. Here is the function:

```
# Function to reshape the image data
reshape_image <- function(image_data) {
  num_images <- nrow(image_data)
  image_size <- 28
  reshaped_data <- array(dim = c(num_images, image_size, image_size))
  for (i in 1:num_images) {
    reshaped_data[i,,] <- matrix(image_data[i,], nrow = image_size, byrow = TRUE)
  }
  return(reshaped_data)
}
```

```
# Reshape the image data
reshaped_data <- reshape_image(features)

# Flatten the 3D image data to 2D for clustering
flattened_data <- matrix(reshaped_data, nrow = nrow(reshaped_data), ncol = dim(reshaped_data)[2] * dim(reshaped_data)[3])
```

I used the reshape_image function to reshape the image data into a 3D array and flatten the 3D image data into a 2D matrix for clustering purposes.
When I run the code, I also get this error: Error in reshape_image(features) :
could not find function "reshape_image"

For dataset link: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/digit-recognizer/data?select=train.csv